# Is this LDAP network traffic normal (Windows Server 2012 R2)?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, wireshark

When this server is attached to our network, the 'upload' speed that every computer on the network drops from ~10mbps to 1 - 2mbps. Is this a DDOS attack, or probing for a vulnerability, or...?[image]

Comment: Based on the destination addresses, it looks like it could be a CLDAP Reflection DDoS attack outbound FROM your server.

Comment: You're going to have to do some investigating. What's installed on the server? Have you scanned it with any AV software? Install and run Microsoft Network Monitor and find the process responsible for the traffic and investigate it.